# Select entire row as range (indefinite number of columns)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formulas

I'm a beginner at Google Apps Script and want to select an entire row after a certain cell to use in a formula.

```
function setUpSheet()
{
  var infoRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("A1:D1");
  infoRange.setValues([ ["Last", "First", "Username", "Total"] ]);
  var cells = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("D2:D");
  var tabRange = ???
  cells.setFormula(["=SUM(tabRange)"]);

}
```

I want to set the formula in the last line to every column following the 'Total' column. For example, I would like D2 to have the sum E2+F2+G2+.....+ an indefinite number of cells in the second row. How would I create a range from E2 to the end of the row? Any help is so much appreciated!!

Comment: `E2:2` will work

Comment: ``"=SUM(tabRange)"`` is ``"=SUM(" + tabRange + ")"``?

Answer (score 7):

Use `number:number` to select all the columns on row `number`.

To include only columns from column `E2` to the last column use `E2:2`.

Regarding setFormula(formula), the argument should be a string, so instead of

```
cells.setFormula(["=SUM(tabRange)"])
```

use

```
cells.setFormula("=SUM(E2:2)")
```